# Mysqli to PDO binding parameters

Tags: php, mysqli, pdo, bind

I am switching from mysqli syntax to PDO and having some doubts:

Before I used this (example of binding int, string, decimal values):

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO MyGuests (firstname, id, value) VALUES (?, ?, ?)");
$stmt->bind_param("sid", $firstname, $id, $value);
$stmt->execute();
```

With PDO I should use this: (here param decimal already doesnt exist, not to mention that I have to write multiple lines for binging)

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO MyGuests (firstname, id, value) VALUES (?, ?, ?)");
$stmt->bindParam(1, $firstname, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(2, $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->bindParam(3, $value, PDO::PARAM_STR);//no decimal type!
$stmt->execute();
```

Should I just 'forget' about types and do this?

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO MyGuests (firstname, id, value) VALUES (?, ?, ?)");
$stmt->execute([$firstname, $id, $value]);
```

How can int and decimal fail in this situation?

Comment: Thing `PDO::PARAM_`  is more for (not only) generating the right sql query with or without quotes. And float/decimal can not just typed like integer `2` they must be with quotes like `'1.1'` in the real executed query, so use `PDO::PARAM_STR` and you are fine. OR forget it like you sayed and use only `execute()`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, most of time you should.

There are only [few extremely rare cases](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo#methods) where you would have to fall bфck to separate binding. While for the both INT and DECIMAL string binding is all right.

Note that for the decimal type you should be using "s" in mysqli as well.

Comment: What if I cast them myself in execute?   $stmt -> execute([$firstname, intval($id), floatval($value)]);

Comment: Well you can but it won't make any difference.

Comment: "Note that for the decimal type you should be using "s" in mysqli as well."

It says 'd' here: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php

Comment: @Toniq nowhere decimal can be seen there. it says double